# App store ranking - effect of downloads from multiple countries

Tags: ios-appstore, ratings, app-store-connect

If I have an app in the app store, it seems to be that the general consensus is

> Higher Downloads = Higher Rank

However, if my app is downloaded 500 times in Australia, will that affect my US ranking? Or are the app stores completely country-independent?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this kind of question, you should try the Apple Dev Fora (http://devforums.apple.com). Beside this, no-one will be able to answer this question 100% sure except Apple engineers, however, we can assume Apple is isolation the stats per store, meaning lot of downloads wont affect the rankings in other stores.